# what determines whether boxplot or outliers are shown?

Tags: dc.js

I have 40 boxplots that each represent 110 companies on page load. The user can filter the companies that drive the boxplots down to a single company. When there's only one company in the filter, I can only see outlier circles and no boxplots, which is what I'd expect. But even when there are 25 companies in the filter, I can still only see outlier circles and no boxplots.

I am going to be asked about this when I present my app, but I can't currently explain what the criteria are for a full boxplot to show instead of outliers. Is it simply the count must be, e.g., >30? Should I be looking in the D3 docs for this since I can't see much in the DC docs? Thanks

Comment: The implementation is based on the [d3-plugins box plot](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/blob/master/box/box.js), and I don't see anything in the source that would remove the boxes. Comments in the source mention that the number of outliers may change but not the number of boxes, and also [this example](http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/examples/box-plot.html) flattens the boxes but doesn't remove them. So I'm confused how you are seeing this.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In fact rect.box remains in place but height is set to zero. For example, when I have 11 datapoints and 10 are zero and 1 is 1, my box has a height of zero and one outlier circle is shown. I would like to understand under what circumstances I get outliers rather than a box. Thanks for the link - that might well answer it, and if it does I'll post here.

Comment: I see, thanks. So I dug into it a little more, and apparently any points which are not contained within the whiskers will be displayed as outliers. Since the values are sorted, this is a range of points at the beginning and a range at the end. Unfortunately the whiskers interval is not customizable right now but it would be easy to add. The current implementation is [strangely complicated](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/blob/356fccea3a1dbd49a76fb1841f280ffad87d725f/src/box-plot.js#L27-L38).

Comment: So I guess the short answer is that the points which are not in the interquartile range will be displayed as outliers. That makes sense for the example you gave above with 10 zeroes and one outlier.